# Razor conditional formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I set a class by condition in razor with shorthand if?

I try:

```
<div class="submenu @{ i==Model.Active ? @:active }">...</div>
```

This doesn't work. What is the shortest way to do it?

Comment: Where is your else part in this condition? It should be "condition==true ? result1 : result2"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following syntax :

```
<div class="submenu @(i == @Model.Active ? "active" : "")">...</div>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Alternative:  `<div class="submenu @(i == Model.Active ? Write(" :active"))">...</div>`

Answer (score 2):

`<div class="submenu @if (i == Model.Active) { @:active }"></div>`